# Google certified shops "google_base_offer_id" not updating when navigating to another product page

Tags: javascript, googlestrustedstore

I currently use the below code in the footer of my Magento store to display the Google Certified Shops badge...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var gts = gts || [];

    gts.push(["id", "12345"]);
    gts.push(["badge_position", "BOTTOM_RIGHT"]);
    gts.push(["locale", "en_GB"]);
    gts.push(["google_base_offer_id", "<?php if (Mage::registry('product')) { echo Mage::registry('current_product')->getId(); } ?>"]);
    gts.push(["google_base_subaccount_id", "123456"]);
    gts.push(["google_base_country", "GB"]);
    gts.push(["google_base_language", "en"]);

    (function() {
        var gts = document.createElement("script");
        gts.type = "text/javascript";
        gts.async = true;
        gts.src = "https://www.googlecommerce.com/trustedstores/api/js";
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(gts, s);
    })();
</script>
<!-- END: Google Certified Shops -->
```

My probelem is with the code

```
gts.push(["google_base_offer_id", "<?php if (Mage::registry('product')) { echo Mage::registry('current_product')->getId(); } ?>"]);
```

This piece of code is meant to get the product ID IF the user is on a product page, and it does but only if I clear my sites cache and then load a product page.
If I then navigate to another product page the value stays the same and doesn't update.
I have tried wrapping the code into an on load function to force it to run again but I still doesn't update each time a new page is loaded.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This is the same thing but a bit cleaner

```
<?php if (Mage::registry('current_product')) : ?>
    gts.push(["google_base_offer_id", "<?php echo Mage::registry('current_product')->getId() ?>"]);
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should use 'current_product' in both the place

```
gts.push(["google_base_offer_id", "<?php if (Mage::registry('current_product')) { echo Mage::registry('current_product')->getId(); } ?>"]);
```

Comment: Yep, probably. This still doesn't get updated each time the page is loaded! :(